# Support for Intel Core 2 Quad and 4GB of RAM

Tags: 10.10, hardware

How to set Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop to take advantage of 
a) Core 2 Quad intel processor
b) 4 GB RAM
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need to configure anything when choosing Ubuntu. If possible any hardware features that are supported are recognized and will be installed by default. I recommend am64 64-bit version for 4 GiB RAM.  Rarely there may be problems with some GPUs, printers or WLAN adapters. It is wise to test your system with a life CD before install.

Comment: The 32bit verison will also support 4GB of RAM with the PAE Kernel. For the boring technical stuff see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension.

Comment: But the 64bit version runs faster and doesn't have any of the software-availability drawbacks that it used to.

Comment: The 64-bit version is faster for some things (because it has more & larger CPU registers) and slower for  other things (larger pointers use more memory, so less code fits in the caches and your main RAM).